# How can you extract the overall stream title from AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm using AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem in Swift to play internet radio streams.

Observing the "timedMetadata" gives me the track currently playing, however I never seem to get a handle of the radio title

See this example using VLC, I can obtain the "Now playing" part easily with timedMetadata, however I never receive the overall title of the radio "Title".

What am I missing, should I be observing something else to access the stream's/shoutcast/icecast information?

[image]

Comment: Just guessing, is "Title" the name of the file? Or is it different from the filename all together?

Comment: It should be used `AVPlayerItemMetadataOutput`, see [Get AVPlayerItem track title with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61372700/12299030) for similar solved issue.

Comment: thanks @Asperi but same issue: I'm only getting the 'now playing' content with that solution.

Comment: @keyle, have you tried the code in my answer?

Comment: @elliott-io haven't had the chance, busy on another project, I will tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let title = AVMetadataItem.metadataItems(from: urlAsset.commonMetadata, withKey: AVMetadataKey.commonKeyTitle, keySpace: AVMetadataKeySpace.common).first?.value as? String
print(title)
```

> This works for media I have with metadata in the title (set using the Apple Music app). If this doesn't work for your media, please post it somewhere online along with your current code.